# Angularjs ocultar y mostrar respuesta formulario

Tags: angularjs, botón

Tengo un formulario para rellenar y hacer el cálculo de un préstamo.

Me aparece el formulario y un botón Enviar. Cuando rellene el formulario y le doy al botón Enviar quiero que se me muestre el resultado.

Estoy trabajando con **Angularjs**. No se como usar el `ng-hide` ni el `ng-show`.

El formulario oculto del resultado del cálculo de la cuota lo tengo, pero no se como mostrarlo al hacer click al boton enviar.

Este es mi código de `Html`:

```
<div class="jumbotron" background-color="#FFF8DC">
    <div style="position:center ; color: #1D66EE">
        <h1>//ABANCA</h1>
    </div>

    <p class="lead">
        Préstamos en 24H.
        Haz tus cuentas.
    </p>

</div>
<body ng-app="pruebaApp">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <form action="http://localhost:58498/api/Cuota" class="form-horizontal"
                  method="get" role="form" id="formulario-cuotas">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="Cuotas">¿Cuánto quieres pedir?</label>
                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                               data-val-cuotas="El campo de las Cuotas está vacío. No es válido"
                               data-val-required="El campo Cuotas es obligatorio." id="Cuotas"
                               name="cantidad" type="number" value="">
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                              data-valmsg-for="Cuotas" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>

                <p>
                    "Con el préstamo 24h puedes pedir a partir <br>
                    de 500€, pero para cantidades de hasta 3000€ <br>
                    tiene que ser en la "<a href="/es/tarjetas/tarjetas-credito/tarjeta-visa-clip" target="_blank">
                        modalidad de
                        tarjeta <br>
                    </a>
                    ".Por eso este simulador empieza en 3000€ que <br>
                    es lo mínimo que puedes pedir en la modalidad <br>
                    de préstamo. Ten en cuenta que no puedes <br>
                    solicitar más de lo que cuesta lo que vayas <br>
                    financiar."
                </p>


                <br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Plazo" class="control-label">¿Cuándo deseas devolverlo?</label>
                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                               data-val-cuotas="El campo de los plazos está vacío. No es válido"
                               data-val-required="El campo Plazos es obligatorio." id="Plazos"
                               name="plazos" type="text" value="">
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                              data-valmsg-for="Plazos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>

                <p>
                    "Puedes devolverlo en un plazo maximo de 96 meses,<br>
                    osea, 8 años"
                </p>

                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="tipo" id="optionsRadios1" value="hipotecario" checked=""><font>
                            <font class="">
                                Crédito Hipotecario.
                            </font>
                        </font>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="tipo" id="optionsRadios2" value="personal" checked=""><font>
                            <font class="">
                                Crédito Personal.
                            </font>
                        </font>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>


            </form>

            <button id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" class="btn btn-primary input-group">
                    ENVIAR
                </button>
            <br>

            <div ng-app="pruebaApp" ng-controller="pruebaAppCtrl"></div>
                <button name="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="color" ng-click="enviar()">
                    NG-ENVIAR
                </button>



                @*<div ng-class="{'hide'}">*@
            </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div ng-show="reulstado">
                      <form method="get" action="http://localhost:58498" class="hide form-horizontal" role="form" id="formulario-respuesta">
                          <br>
                          <br><h3>Resultado:</h3>

                          <div ng-show="resultado"></div>

                          <h4>Cantidad</h4>
                          <div ng-show="contenedor-cantidad"></div>

                          <h4>Cuota</h4>
                          <div ng-show="contenedor-cuota"></div>

                          <h4>Plazos</h4>
                          <div ng-show="contenedor-plazos"></div>

                          <h4>Tipo</h4>
                          <div ng-show="tipo"></div>

                      </form>
                  </div>

                   </div>
               </div>

                       @*</div>*@


 </body>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código de tus controladores? Si puedes armar un ejemplo de lo que tienes en codepen o JSFiddle, sería grandioso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que la ventaja de trabajar con Angularjs es que todo lo que cambie en el controlador se ve reflejado de inmediato en la vista y también viceversa. Para lo que necesitas puedes definir una variable que te permita ocultar y mostrar elementos en tu vista, tambien dar clases dependiendo de una condicion, etc.

Tambien me di cuenta que tu formulario va directamente a la URL de tu API, deberias cambiar esto y hacerlo desde el controlador para utilizar aun mas lo potente de angularJS y trabajar con `ng-model`

En tu controlador deberia ser algo asi :

```
.controller('CalculoCreditoCtrl, [$scope, $http, function($scope,$http){
      $scope.enviar = function() {
        data = data = {nombre : $scope.data.nombre, apellidos : $scope.data.apellidos, cuotas : $scope.data.cuotas}
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:58498/api/Cuota',
            data: data

        }).then(function(response) {
             if(response.respuesta){
                $scope.mostrar_resultado = true;
             }
        });
    }
}])
```

Y en tu vista el formulario deberia ir asi :

```
<div>
     <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                       data-val-cuotas="El campo de las Cuotas está vacío. No es válido"
                       data-val-required="El campo Cuotas es obligatorio." ng-model="data.cuotas"
                       name="cantidad" type="number" value="">
</div>
```

Tu variable `$scope.mostrar_resultado` puedes imprimirla desde tu vista con `{{mostrar_resultado}}` y puedes ocuparla para ocultar o mostrar un elemento `<div ng-show="mostrar_resultado">`

Si te das cuenta borre `id=cuotas` y lo reemplace por `ng-model=data.cuotas`, este tag `ng-model` te permite acceder a los valores de tus inputs desde tu controlador! Esto es una de las ventajas de AngularJS que te ayuda en el manejo de tus datos de forma rapida! , tu codigo no ocupa mucho Angularjs a pesar de que estas implementandolo, te aconsejo que estudies un poco mas de AngularJS para que lo aproveches al maximo!

Te dejo un link muy completo para comenzar con AngularJS

[Tutorial AngularJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4ejmeEals0)

Answer (score 0):

Tu $scope.enviar() que debe estar en el controlador, agregale esta linea:

```
$scope.enviar() {
    $scope.showResult = true;
}
```

Y al div padre de todo el resultado, o div contenedor agregale esto:

```
<div ng-show="showResult">
    Aquí va el resultado
</div>
```

Con ng-show le decimos que muestre o haga visible un elemento HTML solamente si se cumple la condición dada, en este caso si **showResult** es verdadero
 o true.

No es necesario utilizar este bloque que veo en tu código:

```
@*<div ng-class="{'hide'}">*@

@*</div>*@
```

También observo en tu codigo varios ng-show="" , en el resultado, pues estos no son necesarios, con que utilices uno solo en el div contenedor o padre de todo el resultado es suficiente, bueno tambien depende de que tanto quieras ocultar.

Comment: Si, al final le añadi lo que me habias puesto y me va perfectamente!

Comment: muchas gracias :)